# Convert java.io.StringWriter to byte[] array

Tags: java

How to convert `java.io.StringWriter` to `byte[]` array?
Using `OpenCSV` i get `StringWriter` `sw` object and this `sw` object I want to convert into `byte[]` array.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do

```
byte[] bytes = stringWriter.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 17):

You need to decide which encoding you want to use:

- Call [`StringWriter.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html#toString%28%29) to get the contents out *as a string*
- Call [`String.getBytes(Charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29) or [`String.getBytes(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) to convert the string to a byte array

*Don't* use the parameterless `String.getBytes()` call - that will use the platform default encoding. Even if you *want* to use that, I'd strongly encourage you to specify it explicitly, to make it clear to anyone who reads it.