# How to convert Writer to Byte array

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to write blob content to database. I am using a writer Object for this.

That is:
 `OutputStreamWriter writer = getMyWriter();`

I need to know how to convert this writer object to a byte array.?

I need this byte array because , to create blob I pass byte array to the Hibernate entity. I have pasted the code for reference:

```
   public void writeBolobSecuredContentToDb() throws Exception {
    OutputStreamWriter writer = getMyWriter();
    formattedContentToWriter(writer);

   // Writing to Database

     UserPersonal secureData = UserPersonal() 
     userPersonal.fromBytArray("How to convert my writer object to byte array?");
     writer.flush();
     writer.close();
 }

    public OutputStreamWriter getMyWriter() {   
     CipherOutputStream cos = null;
     try {
        cos = getEncrypttedCipherOutputStream();
        return new OutputStreamWriter(cos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not create cipher outputstream.", e);
    }
}


}

//Hibernate entity
public class UserPersonal implements java.io.Serializable
public static Stock fromBytArray(byte[] content) {          
        fileContent.setContent(Hibernate.createBlob(content));
        return (fileContent);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to put into database? From where do you get the data you want to put into db? What does getEncrypttedCipherOutputStream() do?

Comment: You might want to look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453226/convert-java-io-stringwriter-to-byte-array)

Comment: where do you get the data --> formattedContentToWriter() string content add to the writer

Comment: I need to put encrypted content to a ZIP and save as a blob in database. It is happening via  getEncrypttedCipherOutputStream();

Comment: You don't need to convert it to a byte array. You need to get an `OutputStream` from the Blob, and wrap your own `CipherOutputStream`, `ZipOutputStream`, `OutputStreamWriter` etc., around that, then write your data. You're doing this upside down and back to front.

Comment: Hibernate.createBlob() entity level accepting a byte[] it is the easies way to save over other options

Comment: It's not the easiest way if you don't know how to do it.